# Tkinter window with lan socket

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter, lan

I want to build a connection between two lan connected PC If I send some signal Like timer like 5sec then another window should close in 5 sec or like text should appear what I sent from PC1 to PC2.

```
root = tk.Tk()
```

I just got two windows I don't know how should I start with it.
can anyone help me with where should I look for which topic I should go through.

Comment: See official document on [Socket Programming HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html#socket-programming-howto).

Comment: I know Transfering data through socket but don't have any idea about using those data or variables in Tkinter which event I should use.